# Error when assigning a unique pointer that is returned by a function to a variable

Tags: c++

I am using a library called "Pixel Game Engine", which has a `Sprite` and a `Decal` class. The documentation uses `std::unique_ptr` to create them, so I want to do the same to avoid any complications that may come later on.

Here is my code:

```cpp
class Asset
{    
    private:
    
        typedef std::unique_ptr<olc::Sprite> uniqueSprite;
        typedef std::unique_ptr<olc::Decal> uniqueDecal;
    
    private:
    
        uniqueSprite LoadAssetImage(std::string fileName)
        {
            return std::make_unique<olc::Sprite>(fileName);
        }
    
        uniqueDecal MakeDecalFromSprite(uniqueSprite sprite)
        {
            return std::make_unique<olc::Decal>(sprite.get());
        }
    
    public:
    
        uniqueSprite rockSprite = LoadAssetImage("rock.png"); //No Error here
        uniqueDecal rockDecal = MakeDecalFromSprite(rockSprite); //Error here
};
```

Error:

> function "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx> &) [with _Ty=olc::Sprite, _Dx=std::default_delete<olc::Sprite>]" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

At first, I thought this is happening because the `unique_ptr` is being copied, but loading the sprite using `LoadAssetImage()` and assigning it to a variable works fine, so I am a little confused as to why this error is happening.

This is how the documentation loads them:

```cpp
// Load Fragment Sprite
sprFragment = std::make_unique<olc::Sprite>("./gfx/tut_fragment.png");
    
// Create decal of fragment
decFragment = std::make_unique<olc::Decal>(sprFragment.get());
```

But I wanted to try something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MakeDecalFromSprite` passes a `uniqueSprite`  by value, which involves making a copy.  But `std::unique_ptr` has a deleted copy constructor so when you try to call `MakeDecalFromSprite` you get a compilation error.

The solution is to pass `sprite` by const reference instead:

```
uniqueDecal MakeDecalFromSprite(const uniqueSprite& sprite)
...
```

Then, you are not asking the compiler to make a copy.

This call:

```
uniqueSprite rockSprite = LoadAssetImage("rock.png");
```

works because of [NVRO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).  This avoids the need to copy the function result.  If this is not possible for any reason, the compiler can generate a move (`std::unique_ptr` is moveable).